# Should the question's subject be included in the body?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

There are many questions where the question's summary in the subject...

... is continued (as a sentence or a paragraph) on the first line of the question body.

A good example of this is [What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-was-the-robots-name-in-lost-in-space)

```
Subject: What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?

Body:    I don't recall him ever actually being called anything but names by Dr Smith.
```

Someone reading JUST the body does NOT understant anything about the question.

It's a common problem/dilemma with emails, not specific to SciFi SE or SE in general.

I personally STRONGLY prefer the meat of the question to be contained in the body, even if it repeats the subject verbatim (though making subject concisier and body more verbose is preferable).

E.g. I personally feel that the following edit would be a major improvement:

```
Subject: What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?

Body:    What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?

         I don't recall him ever actually being called anything but names by Dr Smith.
```

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

However, when I make these kinds of edits I typically restate the opening line in a new way, or reword the title to be a better attention grabber. A good title isn't always a great opening line to the question.

```
Subject: What was the robot's name in "Lost in Space"?

Body:    Did the robot in "Lost in Space" have a name or designation?

         I don't recall him ever actually being called anything but names by Dr Smith.
```

The title is more a summary of what, hopefully, the answers will be. So if you never read the question itself and jump right to the answers, you shouldn't be disappointed. The question itself should specify the real scope of what you are after and clarify the question. Restate it in as many ways as are needed to make it very clear what a correct answer will look like.

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I'd strive for what you suggested, though I can't say I always see a way to have a short and long forms.